# List all methods / variables in a derived class

Tags: c++

I am working in a legacy project and stumbled upon a use case for modification. My analysis concluded to a class. I was able to trace some methods of the class but as I moved on it became a little tedious in analysis.

Is there a mechanism / method by which I can know all methods (user defined / inherited etc) and its member variables for a given class especially for Linux platform?

Comment: Every IDE should do the job for you. Also vim with ctags is able to give you a list of definitions. The last one maybe without inherited ones...

Comment: Reading through the definition, and the definition of each class in parent hierarchy is the simplest method, although may involve wading through plenty of code if the member functions are defined inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use gdb but that means you have to navigate to that part of the code. If I have a little program:

```
struct AAA {
    int iii;
    int aonly;
    void foo () {
    }
};

struct BBB: public AAA {
    int iii;
    int bonly;
    void fooB () {
    }
};

int main (int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    BBB b;
    b.iii = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

I can compile with debugging symbols (-g in g++), set a break point and print the object:

```
eric@mouni2:/tmp/ttt$ g++ -g a.cpp
eric@mouni2:/tmp/ttt$ gdb a.out
*** output flushed ***
(gdb) b 18
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4004e8: file a.cpp, line 18.
(gdb) R
Starting program: /tmp/ttt/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe278) at a.cpp:18
18      return 0;
(gdb) ptype b
type = struct BBB : public AAA {
    int iii;
    int bonly;
  public:
    void fooB(void);
}
(gdb) p b
$1 = {<AAA> = {iii = -7568, aonly = 32767}, iii = 1, bonly = 0}
(gdb) p b.iii
$2 = 1
(gdb) p b.AAA::iii
$3 = -7568
```

There you see what BBB inherited from AAA. It's not great, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: Many Thanks for the pointers. I can debug the object creation itself - which class constructors are being called and move on